# html, body height 100%

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with the container-about div.
Its height is 100% because I want div occupies the entire width and height after header div.
The problem is that now I do not scroll to show the full text.

We would also like the ability to display text with scroll for tablet and smartphone.

Thanks for Your help.

```
<div class='header'>
   <div class='header-container'>

</div>
</div>
<div class='container-wrapper'>
   <div class='container-about'>
       <div class='about-text'>
            text comes here.....
            ........
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

link: http://ttest11234.librax.net/index.html

css:

```
* {
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
  }

html, body {
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
  }

body {
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 1.5;
background: #000;
font-weight: 400;
}

.header {
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
position: fixed;
background: gray;
opacity: 0.8;
}

.header-container {
width: auto;
height: 100px;
margin: 0 10% 0 10%;
text-align: center;
}

.container-wrapper {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

  .container-about {
    margin: 100px auto;
padding-bottom: 2%;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: #FFF;
position: relative;
}

.container-about h3 {
padding: 0 10% 5% 10%;
font-family: 'Verdana', sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 150%;
font-weight: 400;
}
```

Comment: post it in a fiddle please..

Comment: You can use table element

Comment: table is good only to display tabular data. For all other needs, use divs and CSS. Here, you need to put the CSS property `overflow:auto` on class `.container-about`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `overflow: scroll` `property` in `container-about` `class` and `container-wrapper` `class` of **div**

```
.container-about {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 100px auto;
    overflow: scroll;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simply to add `overflow: auto` to `.container-wrapper`. That gives you the desired scrollbar.

But now your problem is that the div is too high (it's 100% body height + 100 pixels). Give it a `100px` top padding and position the header absolutely.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should not use a fixed top margin for .contain-about, since you are going to use them on mobile devices as that would take a lot more space then desktops. Instead, you could use % or em.
2. set overflow-x to auto or scroll for .about-text to get your scroll bar.

Comment: Your meant `overflow-y`?

Comment: Yup overflow-y, that's it. Just the vertical scroll.